# struct size limitation attention alert

Tags: struct, size, sizeof

In C, how can I make attention alert for overflow of struct size during project increase

Example (my struct at the start of the project

```
//32 bytes size!
typedef struct
{
    u8  Ver:8;
    u8  HasAnyData:8;
    u16 Ymin:16;
    u16 Ymax:16;
    u16 Xmax:16;
    u16 PokerInterval:16;
    u16 PokerDuration:16;
    u16 MinimumWeight:16;
    u32 tmp1:16;
    u32 tmp2:32;
    u32 tmp3:32;
    u32 tmp4:32;
    u32 tmp5:32;
} ConfData_t;
```

And after this definition, I read from flash memory

```
PP_ReadConfig(32,&confData);
```

Maybe problems if struct size will be less than 32 bytes
I should use the calculator for a mistake check.

Is there any standard way for a compiler config?

P.S Instead of `sizeof(confData)`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `C11`, consider [_Static_assert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Static_assert) to check `sizeof` at compile-time.

For example:

```
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct
{
    u8  Ver:8;
    u8  HasAnyData:8;
    u16 Ymin:16;
    u16 Ymax:16;
    u16 Xmax:16;
    u16 PokerInterval:16;
    u16 PokerDuration:16;
    u16 MinimumWeight:16;
    u32 tmp1:16;
    u32 tmp2:32;
    u32 tmp3:32;
    u32 tmp4:32;
    u32 tmp5:32;
} ConfData_t;

int main(){

    static_assert(sizeof(ConfData_t) < 32,
    "needs to be < 32 bytes for flash");
}
```

This will fail to compile if you modify the struct to have a sizeof less than 32.